# Finding limit of a secant?

Tags: limits

I'm supposed to find the limit:

$\lim \limits_{\theta \to \frac{\pi}{2}^+} \sec(x)$

What are all the ways I can solve this problem? I tried graphing it out, but then realized that the secant goes up and down infinitely...

Edit: I found my problem... I thought the limit was where x approached when it was going away from $\frac{\pi}{2}$... lol

Comment: The plus sign above the $\frac{\pi}{2}$ indicates you must consider only the 'right side' of $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: But then when I graph it out, it goes up to infinity, down to negative infinity, and up and down and up and down forever!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Intuitively, you have that $|\sec x| = |1/\cos x|$ goes to $+\infty$ as $x \to \frac{\pi}{2}$. To compute the limit without the absolute value, with $x \to \frac \pi 2^+$, you only have to find out the sign... is it $+$ or $-$? What is the sign of $\cos x$ for $x > \frac \pi 2$, but very close to it?

Comment: I don't get your last sentence... The "sign"?

Comment: Sign is whether the thing is positive or negative.

Comment: About the last sentence, I meant the the result is $+\infty$ or $-\infty$, and the actual sign will be that of $\cos x$ for $x > \pi/2$, but close to it. Make a drawing.

Comment: But when $\cos(x)$ is $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ then it is negative, and when it goes over $\pi$ then it is positive, and goes back to negative again?

Comment: Did you make a drawing?

Comment: I put it on the graphing calculator... Does that count?

Comment: Then what is the sign of, say, $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - 0.00001\right)$?

Comment: I think it's positive.

Comment: You got the idea. Then $\lim_{x \to \frac \pi 2^+}\sec x$ is $-\infty$ or $+\infty$?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's negative, but that's the closest infinity above $\frac{\pi}{2}$... is that it?

Comment: Yup. The limit is $-\infty$. You have $1$ divided by a very very small, but negative number. That goes to $-\infty$.

Comment: ("small" here meaning close to zero)